# Saving 2D Char arrays to file in C++

Tags: c++

So in my program I have a 2d character array `gameField` that has various characters stored in it to represent forts, the player, empty space, and a home base. I am trying to save this array into a file, but the way that I am trying to do is do not seem to be working. This is my sample code.

```
void saveMap()
{
    string userMap = directoryName + username + "-map.txt";
    ofstream savemap(userMap.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j <= COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            savemap << gameField[i][j];
        }

        savemap << endl;
    }

    savemap.close();
 }
```

I keep getting run-time errors whenever I try and execute this, I was wondering if anyone could explain why and perhaps offer an alternative.

**EDIT:** gameField is a character array, `COLUMNS` is equal to 50 and ROWS is equal to 30. I have every single character in the array initialized and set equal to something, but whenever I call the function I'm getting a Unhandled exception at 0x511cbe20 (msvcr100d.dll) in Game1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x30303030.

Comment: And yes, I know Columns is spelled wrong:P

Comment: What runtime errors are you getting? Show that as well.

Comment: and also show what type is `gameField`?

Comment: You probably want some delimiter between rows and the values on each row in your file format, so that you can also read it back.

Comment: @PaulEvans I clearly stated that it is a 2d character array, but I guess that is ambiguous its a char x[i][j] array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access memory beyond the array. For example the valid range for rows is [0, ROWS - 1]

I would write the function the following way

```
void saveMap()
{
   string userMap= directoryName+username+"-map.txt";

   ofstream savemap(userMap.c_str());

   int i = 0;

   while ( i < ROWS && savemap.write( gameField[i++], COLLUMS ) ) savemap << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Im confused, why is it Rows-1, because I have values in gamfield[30][j]

Comment: @Duyve I have not understood what you are asking for. But if the array has ROWS rows then valid elements are in the range [0, ROWS-1]. Indexing in C++ starts from 0. So if for example an array has only one element then its index will be equal to 0.

Comment: I understand how indexing works, but when it is already indexed to have [ROWS] it does not equal rows-1 it equals ROWS. Ihave charactes in gamefield[ROWS][COLLUMS] so there are technically 31 characters in rows and 51 in collums. This is not a soultion to my problem, as it is a 2d character array and your example is 1.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I was initializing the arry incorrectly. Changed the arrays size to be [ROWS+1][COLLUMS+1] and it worked like a charm, thanks!